# Qt library for 2D/3D game development

Tags: c++, qt

As a hobby, I've been working on remaking an old video game, and I want to avoid reinventing the wheel where possible. The game is heavily GUI-based, but the GUI needs to be customized in terms of look-and-feel, and also needs to work with 3D OpenGL rendering for a few game screens.

To give you an idea, here's a screenshot from the initial prototype:

[image]

There's a lot of animation used, and 3D also, but the GUI widgets behave much the same as in a standard desktop application.

Thus far, I've been using my own GUI library (it's not robust or complete, and I've been running into some problems).

I've been considering migrating to Qt given it's reputation and impressive features, and some of the nice screenshots on the Qt website. But I've never used Qt before, so I don't really have an idea of what it's capable of, or what kind of time investment would be required to learn it. (Note I've used FLTK).

My question is: *would it be possible / practical to use Qt in this situation?*

**UPDATE**: After mocking up some game screens in Qt, I've decided not to use it. While it supports many of the features I need out-of-the-box (particularly through Style Sheets), I need to support custom bitmap-based pre-rendered fonts (I can't convert/replace them). And I can't subclass QFont, or reimplement it without it breaking in future Qt releases. That said, I was extremely impressed with Qt (both in its ease of use, and good documentation). I will be borrowing some of its features for my own engine. Thank you to all who provided input.

Comment: The simple answer is yes, its possible/practical to use Qt in this situation. To get a more effective answer, you might consider asking a more detailed question, or listing some of the doubts that you may have about Qt.

Comment: Take a look at the `QGraphicsView`/`QGraphicsScene` architecture, it should be close to what you're after.

Comment: Thanks guys. Well I've never used Qt, so my main concern is spending a lot of time learning it to find it can't do what I need it to. The QGraphicsView class seems to support some of the features I need. Another example feature I need is non-rectangular buttons, e.g. with slanted edges (my existing code uses an image mask to accept/reject mouse events). Will Qt easily allow such feats?

Comment: I'd write a custom paint event instead of using a QGraphicsView. Put this may be a personal opinion. For the non-rectangular buttons, it would be "good enough" (again in my opinion) to treat them rectangular. But it's still possible to apply the same idea you have using a monochromatic image as the "event filter mask". You have to write it for your own, but it should be not that difficult.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm gonna go for Qt. I did some more investigating, and it looks like Qt will actually simplify things for me. For example, QWidget::setMask() will do the trick for non-rectangular widgets. I'm gonna starting watching the training videos on the nokia site now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to know everything your game needs to do based on a screenshot; however, I will echo the sentiments of other posters here and provide a couple of avenues for you to look at.

One, is that you might want to consider QtQuick over the GraphicsView Framework, but this REALLY depends on what you need to do. I just want to throw it out there as an alternative so you don't miss it. This [tutorial](http://quitcoding.com/download/Qt_Quick_Game_Programming_1_0.pdf) uses QtQuick to put together a really slick looking connect four style game. This may be more simplistic than what you want to go for, but then again, maybe it isn't, it depends on what you need to do.

Second, before writing custom paint events for all of your buttons, I would consider using [Qt Style Sheets](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/stylesheet.html) and style your widgets in a CSS like syntax. This will allow you to change the look and feel of your GUI in a very flexible way really quickly. Based on your screenshot, I *think* you can get what you want out of style sheets much faster than subclassing and rolling your own setup. But once again, it's hard to know based on one screenshot. [Here](http://tech-artists.org/forum/showthread.php?2359-Release-Qt-dark-orange-stylesheet)'s an example of a dark and orange GUI that was implemented using only Qt Style Sheets. The `border-radius` property of `QPushButton`'s style sheet would give you the rounded buttons ([ref](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/stylesheet-reference.html)).

Comment: Yes, I stumbled on the style sheets already. The 'border-image' property seems to provide most of the theme functionality I'll need, since I'm mostly using pre-rendered images for everything (hopefully it might do animations too?). It will be especially useful since the game supports multiple playable empires, each one having a different look. With regard to the rounded buttons, the images are already round, I just want to constrain mouse clicks to the area. QWidget::setMask() will do it. I'll check out QtQuick.

Comment: Yes, but with the style sheets it seems like you wouldn't *need* images for your buttons, am I right? You could write up the style and then changes/modifications to the UI (at least in terms of buttons) are that much easier. Then again I don't know your workflow so do whatever suits you best, for sure.

If you're wondering about using animation properties (a la CSS), I don't think you're going to get that with Qt Style Sheets. To my knowledge you're going to have to use the Graphics View Framework or the Animation Framework (and/or some combination of both) to get good animation. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer has been given above but to throw some more thoughts in: yes it's possible, you probably won't need to fight against Qt too much. For the most part the recommended advice for going to heavily customised widgets like that is subclass and implemented the paint event yourself.

You can then use a load of basic drawing primitives to get the basic shapes for the elements and expand from there. There's actually a couple of questions on here with really good resources about how to do it.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that. From what I've seen in the API, it will be pretty easy to subclass widgets to get the exact look-and-feel I want, e.g. by overriding QButton::drawButton() and the like.